# Is it possible to split and put the rest to list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to process a line like this

```
item1 item2 item3 item4_1 item4_2 item4_3 ...
```

And the code is like this

```
data = '''item1 item2 item3 item4_1 item4_2 item4_3'''
for row in data.split("\n"):
    (item1, item2, item3, item4_list) = row.split(' ')
```

It looks like python can't unpack the rest of the items to a list, any ideas?

Comment: How about `(item1, item2, item3, *item4_list) = row.split(' ')`

Comment: @student invalid syntax for both python2 and python3?

Comment: Not sure but for above code it worked fine.

Comment: Python 3 only I think, introduced in [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

Answer (score 2):

For `Python3`, may be you can try (*As Brad Solomon mentioned [link for Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) in comments above*):

```
(item1, item2, item3, *item4_list) = row.split(' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use two steps, and `maxsplit` for [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) this can be python 2 or 3 like:

```
data = '''item1 item2 item3 item4_1 item4_2 item4_3'''
for row in data.split("\n"):
    item1, item2, item3, item4_list = row.split(' ', 3)
    item4_list = item4_list.split(' ')
    print(item1, item2, item3, item4_list)
```

#### Results:

```
item1 item2 item3 ['item4_1', 'item4_2', 'item4_3']
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by student, you want to use extended unpacking syntax—that is, you can put `*rest` directly in the target list (the same way you use `*args` in a function definition), and it will soak up the rest of the values:

```
item1, item2, item3, *item4_list = row.split(' ')
```

If you need something that works in Python 2, there isn’t anything as nice. (They wouldn’t have added extended unpacking if there were already a way to do it that’s just as nice…) The simplest solution here is probably to do it in two steps, using the max-splits argument to `split`:

```
item1, item2, item3, rest = row.split(' ', 3)
item4_list = rest.split(' ')
```